# cut backend subsite on proxy for accessing files as root path

Tags: haproxy

is there a possibility to cut the backend path in case you have a subsite like this:

Frontend: "URL"/**subsite**/index.php
Backend: /index.php

So that in the backend it looks like the rootpath is /

I am not quite understanding how this works, as far as I have googled it has to do with ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

In the `backend` section,

```
http-request replace-path ^/subsite/(.*) /\1 if { path_beg /subsite/ }
```

Comment: thanks for responding that quick, inside the haproxy.cfg ?

Comment: Yes, put that line in the `backend` section of `haproxy.cfg`.  This rewrites the path in the request that goes to the backend server.

Comment: that seems to work fine! however, the root path is still available, is there a possibility to block it? So in other words i can now go to URL/subsite and to URL both shows the same

Comment: You would block it in the `frontend`.  Like `http-request deny deny_status 403 if { ... }` where `...` is the condition for blocking.

Comment: okay according to that for the root path that would be corrent,right? http-request deny deny_status 403 if { path_beg / }

Comment: No, that would block 100% of URLs.  It is not clear to me exactly what you want to block.

Comment: only the access to root without any URI params

Comment: You probably want `path` (exact match) rather than `path_beg` ("path begins with") in that case.

Comment: i have a strange issue, i want to serve CSS files under in the backend folder "/css", however all the other files should be still accessible under root folder "/"

Comment: i thought about doing this http-request replace-path ^/subsite/css/(.*) /\1 if { path_beg /subsite/css/ }, but this cuts out even the CSS folder